# Oracle APEX 18.2 installation issue

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have installed the Oracle 11g and Oracle Apex 18.2 in my win10 machine.
THe 11g installation is successful and the UI(localhost:1158/em) is up and running.However the apex is having some issues.
*http://localhost:8282/pls/apex/apex_admin* is the url but it responds 404 not found error.
I even got the success message after installation. 
Thank you for installing Oracle Application Express 18.2.0.00.12

Oracle Application Express is installed in the APEX_180200 schema.

**I havent removed the apex instance that came along with the 11g package.I am not sure if that would be an issue.If yes please help me remove that instance witout having to uninstall or delete other files.

Can anyone please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is port really `8282`? My 11gXE is on `8080`. If it doesn't help, how about `http://127.0.0.1:8080/pls/...` (instead of *localhost*; also, try port 8282 as well)?

As of 18.2 installation: you shouldn't remove anything. Apex is just *upgraded* to 18.2. The old schema (`APEX_040000` or whichever it is) will remain in the database. Don't worry about it.